# Pymongo error : 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'find' , how to filter it?

Tags: pymongo

I want to query data from mongo and filter them to many stacks
The logic is like:

```
objs = collection.find({"name":"BOB"})

t_list = ["Math","History"]

for t in t_list : 
    subjects = objs.find({{"subjects":t}}) 
    # do_somethig(subjects)
```

But pymongo will raise error  `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'find'`

I want to know can pymongo do this ?? ( query one time and then filter the data I want??)

Comment: `objs` is a [`Cursor`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to fiter ````objs```` like django orm. for example : filter ````objs```` which Math score grater than 40, or history score grater than 60 , spend how many time study math in last 3 days....

Comment: did you ever discover an answer?